SignalR WebSocket Connection Fails When Hosted in IIS
I have a Web API hosted in IIS that uses SignalR. When I try to connect to the SignalR hub endpoint, I encounter the following error:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://10.0.72.35:4231/hub' failed:

Failed to start the connection: Error: WebSocket failed to connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the endpoint may not be a SignalR endpoint, the connection ID is not present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. If you have multiple servers, check that sticky sessions are enabled.

When I access the endpoint directly in the browser (http://10.0.72.35:4231/hub), it responds with:
Connection ID required
However, if I test the application on my development machine (using visual studio kestrel), it works perfectly fine. This suggests that the server configuration in IIS might be the issue.
Here’s how I configure the SignalR client connection:
NLHubConnection.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .withUrl(`${this._serverBaseUrl}/hub`, {
        accessTokenFactory: () => accessToken, // Uses the token in Authorization header
        skipNegotiation: true,
        transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
    })
    .configureLogging("warn")
    .build();

What I've tried:

Confirmed that the Web API and SignalR are correctly configured in the project.

Checked the IIS configuration to ensure WebSocket Protocol is enabled.

Verified that there’s no proxy blocking WebSocket traffic.

Confirmed the access token is being passed properly.



It looks like your code also includes authentication. Did you give sufficient permissions after deployment? And is the application pool Identity configured correctly?

Everything looks correct in configurations. Before the SignalR endpoint client sends regular http request to login and there is no issue. Problem appears when client tries to connect singalR hub
